# How to use a separate file system for the Docker daemon related files at start up on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ami

I would like to use a separate overlayfs file system volume for the Docker daemon on AWS EC2. I have been able to configure and set this up myself manually by logging in and running the commands. I would now like to create an AWS AMI that does this automatically on start up so I don't have to do this myself each time.

I've tried googling this but I can't seem to find an AMI that does this already. Could anyone offer a suggestion on the best way to go about baking this into my custom AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working out how to do this myself. I'm posting my results in case
this is of any use to anyone else.

### Creating an AMI

Assuming a base AMI that already has docker installed and using systemctl to
manage start up services. I ran the following commands to switch from the
docker daemon from using devicemapper to using overlayfs. Furthermore the old
`/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` directory is removed, and the flag
`--graph=/mnt/` specifies that directory `/mnt` will be used to store all the
docker images, containers, and etc.

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/devicemapper
sudo sed -i -e "/ExecStart/s/$/ --storage-driver=overlay --graph=\/mnt\//" /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Next create the directory where the file system will be mounted. Update
`/etc/fstab` that it is mounted when the EC2 instance starts.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt
echo '/dev/xvdf       /mnt    ext4    defaults,nofail 0 2' | sudo tee --append /etc/fstab
```

Create an new amazon AMI with these changes. I used [packer](https://www.packer.io/) for this and
found it quite straightforward.

### EBS Snapshot

You'll need an already formatted EBS snaphot to attach to each launched EC2
instance. I did this by creating a EC2 instance with a new EBS volume,
formatting the attached EBS volume. The [AWS website has documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html),
for example formatting as Ext4 is:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 device_name
```

Once you've done this you'll need to turn the EBS volume into an EBS snapshot.
You can do this by going in the AWS, and clicking "EC2" -> "Volumes" (Left
Menu). Then select the volume attached to the EC2 instance and select "Actions"
-> "Create Snapshot". It'll then take a few minutes to create the snapshot.

### Launching an instance

Once you've done all of this you should have the following:

- An AMI expect a mounted device at `/dev/xvdf`.
- A Docker daemon configured to save it's graph database to a volume under /mnt.
- An Ex4 formatted EBS snapshot to be used as this volume.

I then used the following `BlockDeviceMappings` configuration to mount this
snapshot as a volume when launching the instance. Replace the all caps values
with your values. You should use the AMI you created to launch the instance. I
used the `DeleteOnTermination : true` because I don't care about the docker
related files after I shutdown the instance.

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdf",
    "Ebs": {
      "SnapshotId": "SNAPSHOT_ID",
      "Encrypted": false,
      "DeleteOnTermination": true,
      "VolumeSize": VOL_SIZE
    }
  }
],
```

### Trouble shooting

- Make sure to use an base AMI that can use EBS volumes
- Make sure your EBS volume is formatted with as a file system e.g. Ext4
- Check whether `/dev/xvdf` is the mounted device and adjust accordingly if
  not.
- See my [packer github repository](https://github.com/nucleotides/nucleotides-ami) for the commands I used to build my
  AMI.